# How add hash-key in form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a model attribute 'options', and I want record to it a hash with a few parameters.For example:

```
options:
    name: 'username'
    address: 'useraddress'
    age: 'userage'
```

To do this, I use *serialize*

```
  serialize :options, Hash
```

how to make the right form for this to work

how make it?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

In model use

```
 serialize :options
```

and when you save your `options` to `db` do it like:

```
object.options = {name: 'username', address: 'useraddress', age: 'userage'}
object.save # in database it will save hash as string, but serialize it.
```

When you read `options` from `db`,

```
opt = User.first.options # ou will get Hash object
# opt = {name: 'username', address: 'useraddress', age: 'userage'}
# opt is now a Ruby Hash object
```

In your view, you have to add 3 input fields

```
<input type='text' name='user[options_name]'>
<input type='text' name='user[options_address]'>
<input type='text' name='user[options_age]'>
```

In your controller you will have

```
params[:user][:options_name], params[:user][:options_address], params[:user][:options_age]
```

Use these 3 variables to set the value of your options field, but set it as Hash

Comment: mm, I seem poorly explained.I know how write it from irb, I want make it from views with 'form_for' helper

Comment: You will need to handle the logic at your server side, but there are few solutions

Comment: And what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem like this

view with form

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.fields_for :options do |o|
    = o.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Name"
    = o.text_field :useraddress, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Say your price"
    = o.text_field :useraddress, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter your address"
```

permit params in controller

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, options: [:name, :price, :address])
end
```